# Why does bot.get_channel() produce NoneType?

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I'm making a Discord bot to handle an announcement command. When the command is used, I want the bot to send a message in a specific channel and send a message back to the user to show that the command was sent.

However, I cannot get the message to be sent to the channel. I tried this code:

```
import discord
import os
import random
import asyncio

testing_servers = [912361242985918464]
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)

@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=testing_servers, name="announce", description="Make server announcements!")
async def announce(ctx, title, text, channel_id,anonymous=None):
    #response embed
    print(channel_id)
    #announcement embed
    embed_announce = discord.Embed(
        colour = discord.Colour.blue(),
        title=str(title),
        description = text
    )
    await bot.get_channel(channel_id).send(embed = embed_announce)
```

But before even attempting to send the other message back to the user, I get an error that says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`.

I conclude that `bot.get_channel(channel_id)` evaluated to `None`. But why? How can I get the correct `Channel` to send the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are sending an integer to `get_channel()`:

```
await bot.get_channel(int(channel_id)).send(embed=embed_announce)
```

Comment: You could also type hint `channel_id` as an `int` or `TextChannel` in the parameter list

Comment: Worth noting: Python does not really care about type annotations on functions - it will not do its own type checking or conversion. However, it does *attach metadata* to the function, which the decorator *can (and does) inspect* in order to change the behaviour of the decorated (wrapped) function.