# How to send message to a specific discord channel

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to send a message to a specific channel and I can run the code below just nothing show up on the channel and I have no idea why... I put the channel Id in the get_channel input, just putting a random number here.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

async def send_msg(msg):
    channel = client.get_channel(123456456788)
    await channel.send('hello')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I send a message in a specific channel with pycord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71581084/how-do-i-send-a-message-in-a-specific-channel-with-pycord)

Answer (score 1):

Is the function even called somewhere? Otherwise there could also be an issue with the discord permissions or the Intents.

This is one of many ways to call the function and post 'hello' in some specific channel. No msg parameter is required.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await send_msg()

async def send_msg():
    channel = client.get_channel(123456456788)
    await channel.send('hello')
```

Comment: I tried this and it is still not showing the message in the channel, I think it is the discord permissions or the intents like you mentioned, I am thinking I might need to pass in my discord token or something.